# joomla third level menu 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

i am working on a joomla website and seem to be having a bug with 2.5.

I want to keep proper hierarchy in the menus so i have tags under "search" like so

```
parent - main page for area "static"
 search - search page for advanced search
       tag - tag page
       tag - tag page
```

*I am using k2 for the tags

I have the menu setup like that, however when i make a module to show from the third level, nothing shows. However when i change it to the second level with sub items, the third level will show.

We have tried different menu plugins, as well as deleting and remaking the menu items, nothing seems to fix this. I would say its a bug with joomla 2.5, but we don't want to have to hack this to work when it "should" be fixed in a new version. Did anyone else have a similar problem and got it to work? or is this bug more or less isolated to us (the joomla install)?

If any more details are needed i will be happy to try and provide more, the situation is confusing for us as joomla allows up to ten levels of menus natively.

UPDATE: Searching we finally gave up on this, it seems to be something that would need some sort of plugin, and wanting to avoid using more plugins then needed for something so simple we are making a static menu.

Comment: And you're on one of the 2nd-level pages? You wouldn't be able to see those items unless you're on the parent page.

Comment: That does make sense, but doesn't make it proper. That could be what were missing. it is on the parent page of search, not in search itself.

Comment: you can have 3 levels, but all 3 should be visible at the same time on the page; I have it setup as such and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to not be possible in the current joomla structure. We changed our thoughts on how to approach this and eventually went with a static solution.